# Combining data into one table cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a query that returns a temporary table.
TSQL Query:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SOH.OrderDate AS DATE) as DateYMD,
    P.LastName,
    P.FirstName,
    PP.[Name] + ' Qty: ' + CAST(SOD.OrderQty AS varchar(10)) as [OrderContent]

FROM Person.Person as P
    JOIN Sales.Customer SC ON P.BusinessEntityID = SC.PersonID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader as SOH ON SC.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
    AND SOH.SalesOrderID = (
        SELECT TOP 1 subSOH.SalesOrderID
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as subSOH
        WHERE subSOH.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
        ORDER BY subSOH.OrderDate DESC 
    )
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail as SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
    JOIN Production.Product as PP ON SOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID
```

Result:
[Random sampling of output values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/697Sv.png)

Is it possible to group data from the last column, thereby reducing the number of lines in the output. That is, I need it to be like this: [Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXq0j.png)

UPD: SQL Server 2016. STRING_AGG is missing

Comment: Would `STRING_AGG` work? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Can I use it in GROUP BY?

Comment: Yep, group by your other fields (date, first name, last name)! The answer below seems to have done it, good luck!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to point out that work comes with SQL Server version 16. STRING_AGG is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the values you need (DateYMD,LastName,FirstName) and [STRING_AGG](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-string_agg-function/) can do this

```
Select DateYMD,LastName,FirstName, STRING_AGG(OrderContent,';') order_contents from
(
SELECT 
    CAST(SOH.OrderDate AS DATE) as DateYMD,
    P.LastName,
    P.FirstName,
    PP.[Name] + ' Qty: ' + CAST(SOD.OrderQty AS varchar(10)) as [OrderContent]

FROM Person.Person as P
    JOIN Sales.Customer SC ON P.BusinessEntityID = SC.PersonID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader as SOH ON SC.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
    AND SOH.SalesOrderID = (
        SELECT TOP 1 subSOH.SalesOrderID
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as subSOH
        WHERE subSOH.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
        ORDER BY subSOH.OrderDate DESC 
    )
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail as SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
    JOIN Production.Product as PP ON SOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID ) q 
    group by DateYMD,LastName,FirstName
```

---

STUFF  FOR XML PATH for sqlserver 16 :

```
WITH tbl (DateYMD, LastName, FirstName ,  OrderContent)  
AS  
(  -- it is your query
SELECT 
    CAST(SOH.OrderDate AS DATE) as DateYMD,
    P.LastName,
    P.FirstName,
    PP.[Name] + ' Qty: ' + CAST(SOD.OrderQty AS varchar(10)) as [OrderContent]
FROM Person.Person as P
    JOIN Sales.Customer SC ON P.BusinessEntityID = SC.PersonID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader as SOH ON SC.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
    AND SOH.SalesOrderID = (
        SELECT TOP 1 subSOH.SalesOrderID
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as subSOH
        WHERE subSOH.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
        ORDER BY subSOH.OrderDate DESC 
    )
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail as SOD ON SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
    JOIN Production.Product as PP ON SOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID
)
Select distinct  DateYMD, LastName,  FirstName ,  
, STUFF((
       SELECT ',' + t1.OrderContent
         FROM tbl t1
        WHERE t1.DateYMD = t2.DateYMD and t1.LastName = t2.LastName and  t1.FirstName = t2.FirstName 
        ORDER BY t1.OrderContent
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS OrderContents
            from tbl t2
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to point out that work comes with SQL Server version 16. STRING_AGG is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You say you only have SQL Server 2016. So you will have to use the `FOR XML` aggregation method

```sql
SELECT 
    CAST(SOH.OrderDate AS DATE) as DateYMD,
    P.LastName,
    P.FirstName,

    STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT(',', PP.[Name], ' Qty: ', SOD.OrderQty)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail as SOD
        JOIN Production.Product as PP ON SOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID
        WHERE SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
      1, LEN(','), '') as [OrderContent]

FROM Person.Person as P
    JOIN Sales.Customer SC ON P.BusinessEntityID = SC.PersonID
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 subSOH.*
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as subSOH
        WHERE subSOH.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
        ORDER BY subSOH.OrderDate DESC 
    ) SOH;
```

Note the use of `OUTER APPLY` to get the top `SalesOrderHeader` per `CustomerID`. You could also use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much @Charlieface for demonstrating this solution. I nevertheless made the request a little in my own way, because an additional condition was to make a selection of the very first order for each customer.
The final solution to my problem:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(SOH.OrderDate AS DATE) as DateYMD,
    P.LastName,
    P.FirstName,
STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT(',', PP.[Name], ' Qty: ', SOD.OrderQty)
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail as SOD
        JOIN Production.Product as PP ON SOD.ProductID = PP.ProductID
        WHERE SOH.SalesOrderID = SOD.SalesOrderID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
      1, LEN(','), '') as [OrderContent]
FROM Person.Person as P
    JOIN Sales.Customer SC ON P.BusinessEntityID = SC.PersonID
    JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader as SOH ON SC.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
    AND SOH.SalesOrderID = (
        SELECT TOP 1 subSOH.SalesOrderID
        FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as subSOH
        WHERE subSOH.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID
        ORDER BY subSOH.OrderDate DESC 
    )
ORDER BY LastName ASC
```